# ORMLite - Foreign Object

Tags: orm, ormlite, foreign-collection

How do i use Foreign properly with ORMLite?

I have a class currencypair, it constists of 2 instances of the class currency.
I understand, that the DB will not save the instances, but their ID.

Here the relevant parts of those classes.

```
DatabaseTable(tableName = "CurrencyPairs")
public class CurrencyPair {
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private int id;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "baseCurrency_ID", **foreign** = true )
    private CCC_Currency baseCurrency;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "quotedCurrency_ID", **foreign** = true )
    private CCC_Currency quotedCurrency;    
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "subscribed")
    private boolean subscribed;
```

and

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "CCC_Currencies")
public class CCC_Currency {

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "currencyName")
    private String currencyName;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "shortName")
    private String shortName;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "symbol")
    private String symbol;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "isFiat")
    private boolean isFiat;

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;
```

When i now load the Currencypairs with

```
    try {
        CurrencyPair_Dao = DaoManager.createDao(dbHandler.getInstance(),
                CurrencyPair.class);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Get Objects and add them to the library
    List<CurrencyPair> all = null;
    try {
        all = CurrencyPair_Dao.queryForAll();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It creates currencyPairs in the list all, but they are fields (example baseCurrency) are null.
Somehow the ID isn't linked to the objects themselves.

What am i missing?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to persist one instance of CCC_Concurrency, so OrmLite will set a generated id. then set this instance on the object of ConcurrencyPair, and persist it.